# Beginner can´t enable cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I started to learn PBR texturing (with Blender 3, iMac Mojave).
To see texture displacements, I was told to enable cycles but it didn´t show up in the render tab.

I was told to check  „Surfaces“ first in the „Layer-Filter“ menue, so cycles will show up.
But I cannot find „Surfaces“ or "Filter" in the Layer-menue - could you help me?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The render engine can be selected in the *Render Properties* tab.

[image: Render engine selection]

If Cycles does not appear in the selection, then you should enable the add-on on in the preferences (*Edit > Preferences > Add-ons*).

[image: Add-on preferences]

You should also check that you have not accidentally enabled the filtering of add-ons. Open the sidebar (<kbd>N</kbd>) and navigate to the tool tab. Ensure that *Filter Add-ons* is disabled.

[image: Filter Add-ons]

Comment: Oh, the preferences - I didn´t look there, thank you so much!